# "Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined" and stop server in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm trying to build logging application in node JS. in here password authentication app do not work properly. when i enter username and password it occur following error and stop server.

```
this is the error.
```

[image]

Here is the code for authentication part

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
       if(err) throw err;
       if (!user) {
           return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
       } 

       User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
           if(err) throw err;
           if (isMatch) {
               return done(null, user);
           } else {
               return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
           }
       });
    });
}));
```

This code work for Unknown user.
but it is not working for comparing username and password. i cannot see any bug in here. i want a help for solve this.

Comment: What are the values of `password` and `user.password` when you call `.comparePassword()`? It looks like it's complaining that `user.password` is `undefined`.

Comment: "password" is user input value for login. "user.password" is value that stored in database. according to the username it refers for password and compare with value that user entered.

Comment: OK. What is the value of `user.password`?

Comment: I found the problem. there are same username stored in the database. thats why it occur error. Because it will be a problem for authenticating and compare passwords. because it has to compare same username with many password. I should validate that also. thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4):

In the name of the universe programmer

in my case i forgot to select the password
because in database the password was ((select: false))

this code for app

```
const user = await User.findOne({email}).select("+password")
```

i forgot to append the ((.select("+password")))to the findOne

and I received this error ;
Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

and this code for database

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required: [true,"نام کاربری ضروری است"]
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required: [true,"رایانامه ضروری است"],
        unique: true,
        match:[
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{1,3})$/,
            "لطفا یک رایانامه صحیح وارد کنید"
        ]
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"رمز ضروری است"],
        minlegth: 5,
        select: false
    }
})
```

Comment: .select("+password") Work's for me, cuz in my model User i have password: select:false
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem in here. it is not things regarding the code.

The thing is i had registered two users with same user name and different password. then when i tried to login with the user name and one password it occurred this error and stop the server.

Because there is embarrassing situation with find password to username that user entered. because there are two password with same username.

Comment: How did you deal with that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using social signin/signup. When the user is signing up using a social login option, the value of the password stored is "NULL".

So I just added this little check :

```
  comparePassword: function(password, user){
    if (!user.password)
      return false;
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using arrow function

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async (enterdPassword) => {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enterdPassword, this.password);
};
```

which I converted to normal function

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (enterdPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enterdPassword, this.password);
};
```

that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

At

"models/user.js"

Inside comparePassword

```
module.exports.comparePassword = (candidatePassword, hash, callback) => {...)
```

Add this code:

```
bcrypt.hash(candidatePassword, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here We are  grabbing username and password from the sign in page AND
finding our  user by the username from the database and then
Matching its encrypted password with an entered password by the user

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    (username,password,done)=> {
        db.users.findOne({username: username},(err, user)=> {
            if(err) return done(err);

            if(!user) {
                return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect Username'});
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password,(err,isMatch)=> {
                if(err) return done(err);
                if(isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false,{message: 'Incorrect Password'});
                }
            });
         });
      }
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply await to your salt and password assignments too.

Like this,

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const password = await req.body.password;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can write a code like this: After this.findOne({ select: [] ........}) ... I hope this is helpful**

```js
async validateUserPassword(loginDto: AuthLoginDto): Promise<User> {
    const { mobile, email, password } = loginDto;
    const user = await this.findOne({
      select: ['id', 'email', 'mobile', 'password', 'salt', 'status', 'logged_at'],
      where: [
        { mobile: mobile },
        { email: email }
      ]

    });

    if (user && await user.validatePassword(password)) {
      const logged_at = {
        logged_at: new Date()
      }
      await this.update({ id: user.id }, logged_at)
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, this.salt);
    return hash === this.password;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own case , I just want to check if the old password matches the password in Db but got the error , here is my code below:

```
changePassword = asyncHandler (async (req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)
  const {oldPassword, password} = req.body

  if(!user) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("User not found, please signup")
  }

  // Validate
  if(!oldPassword || !password) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("Please add old and new password")
  }

  // Check if old password matches password in DB
  const passwordIsCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password)

  // Save new password
  if(user && passwordIsCorrect) {
    user.password = password
    await user.save()
    res.status(200).send("Password change successful")
  } else {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("Old password is incorrect")
  }

});
```

Comment: If this is a question, please post it as a new one, instead of an answer to existing question. Cheers.

Comment: I fixed it ,  I added .select("+password") to where I got the user by id

Answer (score 0):

for my case I havn't gave "await" keyword when I was writing code to connect to  database and find the password, so I got the same error

```
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {

  const userdata = req.body;
  const enteredEmail = userdata.email;
  const enteredPassword = userdata.password;

  const existingUser =await db
      .getDb()
      .collection("users")
      .findOne({ email: enteredEmail });

  if (!existingUser) {
    console.log('Could not log in!')
    return res.redirect('/login')
  }

  const passwordsAreEqual = await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, 
existingUser.password);

  if (!passwordsAreEqual) {
    console.log("Could not log in! Incorrect Password");
    return res.render('/login')

  }
  console.log('User is authenticated');
  res.redirect('/admin');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

1: Go to your model and check for, select property. If true or false.

2: If it is false, then you need to manually query it.

**Example:**

Suppose password field in our model look like this.

```
// using mongoose
const userShema = new mongoose.Schema({
// All other fields
password: {
    type: String,
    select: false, // By default not selected. Require manual query
  },
});

// Rest of the stuff
```

Now getting this password along with other data.

```
  // Find user by id and also select the password field in the result
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select("+password");
  
 // log it
 console.log(user.password);

 // rest...
```

*Note: User proper async await & try catch.*